# Google Visualization API, making a line graph

Tags: javascript, api, google-visualization

I am trying to make a [line](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/linechart.html) chart by using the Google Visualization API, here is my column data definition:

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

dataTable.addColumn('date', 'Date');
dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Uptime');
dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Channel');
```

I want to group my rows by channels and these grouped channels make a line where X axis is the date and the Y axis is the uptime. I am pretty lost at the API and would be greatful of any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you create the data then you add it to the chart:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
// 3 columns
dataTable.addColumn('date', 'Date');
dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Uptime');
dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Channel');

// Add 2 rows
data.addRows(2);
// setValue(row, col, value)
data.setValue(0,0, '2009-09-06');
data.setValue(0,1, 1000);
data.setValue(0,2, 'Channel1');
data.setValue(1,0, '2009-09-05');
data.setValue(1,1, 100);
data.setValue(1,2, 'Channel2');

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart('chartDiv');
chart.draw(data, {
  width: width,
  height: height,
  is3D: true,
  title: title,
  colors: colors,
  enableTooltip: false,
  legend: 'bottom' });
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't want `google.visualization.LineChart(blah)` instead of `google.visualization.DataTable()`? I mean, you said you wanted a line chart and the documentation says that it's LineChart which you want. Also, tinkering on the [playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart) might be informative.

Comment: Ah! I see what the problem could be. Now that you've added a column to the table, you need to add some rows using addRow or use setCell or setValue to put data in there. Have you tried that?